# Integrating UIKit (Specifically Storyboards) into Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am working through this tutorial at the moment:

http://www.koboldtouch.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8520073

I'm trying to add a Storyboard to a current Cocos2D app template and I am getting the same result every time. All I seem to get is console warning of:

"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

I have tried using both the Kobald2D and Cocos2D templates with this particular tutorial but noting seems to be working.

My code is exactly the same as what is in the tutorial so if anyone can try it and let me know if they get a different result and what they did to get this working I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.